# Regular expression to remove parenthesis and space before it

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a regular expression (inside a Google Spreadsheet) to remove parenthesis, the text inside the parenthesis, and space before the parenthesis. Or in other words, I'm trying to extract only the name inside of the text. For example, I'd like the string "A.J. Smith (iOS Developer, San Francisco)" to become "A.J. Smith"

So far I've gotten both `=REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"[^()]*")` and `=REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"^[^(]+")` to extract "A.J. Smith " but it leaves that last space at the end. This is probably a really easy problem to solve, I'm just not great with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use word boundary.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"^[^(]+\\b")
```

`^[^(]+` greedily matches all the characters upto the first `(` symbol including the space which exists before `(`. Then it backtracks to the last word boundary appears on the matched string because of `\b` present in the regex.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aN6dS2/1)

Comment: It works for me if I do `=REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"^[^(]+\b")` with one backslash in `\b`

Comment: is double backslash fails?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(D2,"\s\(.*","")
```

What I'm doing is replacing everything from a space next to a parenthesis to the end of the string with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I used https://regoio.herokuapp.com/ to help build a regex to match. This regex would match this example without the space. `^(.+)\s\(`
The regex works like this, The `^` matches the beginning of the string, the parenthesis captures whatever expression is inside that you want to use. in this case `.+` which matches any character 1 or more times. The `\s` matchs a whitespace character and `\(` matches the opening parenthesis.

If you want a regex that removes whitespace at the beginning of the string and any before the parenthesis this should work: `^[\s]*(.+)[\s]+\(`

With this regex you can extract all the text you wanted in a single `REGEXEXTRACT` instead of using multiple ones:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"^[\s]*(.+)[\s]+\(")`

Answer (score 0):

I found that `=REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"(.*)\s\(")` also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work to remove all parentheses and white space before:

`=REGEXTRACT(D2,"\s|\(|\)|\[|]|{|}|")`

Feel free to play around with this on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/w1wauZcDQp).